# Wordpress Custom Logo with Description text

Tags: wordpress

my Question is, is there anyway to add some descrption text to the Custom Logo Section. Like the description text you can see at website icon. See Screenshot attached. I wanna add some text under the word "Logo". Something like: "Your Logo should be 200px x 150px."

The Wordpress Codex doesn´t say anything about that. Is just width, height, flex width/height, header-text.

[image: Screenshot Customizer]

Comment: The question is not that clear. Are you trying to add text below logo or onhover?

Comment: Edited my question, i want to add some text under "Logo". Something like: "Your logo should be 250px x 150px".

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to add the text to the WordPress editing interface right? I don't really have much that part, but maybe reading [this](https://themeisle.com/blog/customize-wordpress-admin-interface/) about customizing the WordPress admin will get you on your way?

Comment: Thanks for the link, but unfortunately not helpful for what i need :'‑(